# What is the correct implementation of handling concurrent SQL inserts while ensuring a non-primary key column (i.e. wid) unique and auto-incremental?

Tags: mysql, database, transactions

What is the correct implementation of handling concurrent SQL inserts while ensuring a non-primary key column (i.e. wid) unique and auto-incremental?

Note: There was a design constraint that led this field (i.e. wid) in not becoming the primary key. A separate auto-increment PK is included in the column called id. Changing the wid to PK is not feasible as the database design is now heavily coupled to multiple software projects. So I need to devise a workaround.

I'm thinking of 3 possible ways:

1.) Reserving the wid by executing a transaction and proceeding with other SQL statements which should have been included in the same transaction. The reservation is executed in a separate transaction to make the locking as short as possible. However, if the subsequent transaction failed (e.g. due to database connection issues), then the invalidated row containing the reserved wid will remain in the table.

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET @wid_d = 0;
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(`wid`), 0) INTO @wid_d FROM table
WHERE `wid >= 0 AND `wid <= 1000 FOR UPDATE;
INSERT INTO table (`wid`) VALUES (IF (@wid_d = 0, 1, @wid_d+1) )
COMMIT;
```

2.) Including the reservation of wid in the entire transaction to eliminate the problem of insertion of invalidated row, should the transaction fail but this approach prolongs the locking of tables.

3.) Rely on the failure of transaction calls for re-executing the transaction until it performs successfully; should the transaction fail due to the race condition of inserting the same MAX(wid) + 1. This approach will prevent insertion of invalidated rows but the problem is the number of times the transaction should be re-run. There is also no distinction of knowing the problem that is caused by the conflicting wid or other problems, hence, this is a problematic approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, depending on how brave you are you have other options, like create separate sequence table that will be used to maintain WID values:

```
CREATE TABLE wid_seq (wid INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT);
```

and in your transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO wid_seq VALUES (null);
INSERT yourtable (WID) values (LAST_INSERT_ID());
COMMIT;
```

Comment: If I implemented it this way, then the number of tables will be doubled since every table must have a dedicated sequence table right?

Comment: That's depending on your application. If you are after Auto increment PK functionality then you need to have one table for that one 'simulated' column.

Comment: If this were so, no wid column in any table will contain the same wid since they are based on one sequence table, which implies that the rate of "reaching-the-overflow-value" though may still be far away if the column becomes a BIGINT will be exponentially higher. Won't it be a waste of space if every column would need to be BIGINT as they share only one sequence?

Comment: You have the same constraints as if the column in sequence table would be Auto_increment PK in `yourtable`.Would you need BIGINT in that case and would it be waste of space?

Comment: But if the auto increment PK is in yourtable, then each table sequence is independent from any other table; compared to having all tables share the sequence generator table. For the former case, if table A has wid of 10001, then the rest of the tables cannot have that 10001. Unlike the latter case, the rest of the tables may still have 10001. This is what I refer as waste of space; if they share in one generator table.

Comment: No, the point is that the sequence table is only used to generate unique values, just like AI PK, which are then stored in a column in some other table. It's up to you to decide where you store it, or whether to store it in multiple tables. You may even run `DELETE FROM wid_seq;` after every insert to preserve space and it *still works* because only `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, and how you use it, is meaningful.

Comment: I get your point but it does not seem to answer my question. I should not have used the phrase "waste of space", it may be ambigious. I'm sorry, Let me rephrase, even if I deleted the generated rows, and retrieved and inserted the last inserted id into my tables, the index is already auto incremented. For instance, if table A had 1001 as wid derived from the sequence generator table and another table B, having empty initial rows, should have its wid column start at 1001 also since it is the first wid, yet since they share one generator, it will get 1002 wid. Is this what is bound to happen?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what would happen, just like with AI PK. Auto Increment keeps going, even if you delete all rows. If you need to have different sequences in tables A and B, then you need two sequence tables as well. Yes, if each table needs to have their own sequence then you'll double number of tables. If that's really needed, then you should strive to make `wid` AI PK in each table or resort to solution that scans the table for suitable available wid.

Comment: Okay. Seems like this is the only option. May I know your insight of the possible problem of the first solution?

Comment: First downside is that you'll end up with abandoned rows instead of gaps in the sequence. Second potential problem is the need for table scan (to find `MAX(WID)`) but whether that's a problem or not depends on your data. You'll also end up with two transactions instead of one.